# select from autocomplete dropdown

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright

I have below HTML and trying to select from the list but it return empty array. What should I do???

```
<div id="cdk-overlay-1" class="cdk-overlay-pane"> </div>
     <div role="listbox" class="mat-autocomplete-panel" id="mat-autocomplete-1"> </div>
<mat-option role="option" class="mat-option mat-focus-indicator ng-star-inserted" id="mat-option-35">
  </mat-option>
  <mat-option role="option" class="mat-option mat-focus-indicator ng-star-inserted" id="mat-option-36"> </mat-option>
  <mat-option role="option" class="mat-option mat-focus-indicator ng-star-inserted" id="mat-option-37"> </mat-option>
  <mat-option role="option" class="mat-option mat-focus-indicator ng-star-inserted" id="mat-option-38"> </mat-option>
  <mat-option role="option" class="mat-option mat-focus-indicator ng-star-inserted" id="mat-option-39"> </mat-option>
```

```
await page.click('input[placeholder="search"]')
await page.keyboard.type('e');
await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
  
const listbox = await page.$("div[role='listbox']")
const opt= await listbox?.$$("mat-option[role='option']");
        const allUrls = await Promise.all(opt?.map(async (option, i) => {
            return await option.innerText()
        }))
        console.log(opt);
```

Comment: What's the thing with the `await`? Why you have to put it everywhere? Those operations *should* be synchronous, and no doubt it won't work... What's `opt` returning? If it's a proper list of elements, and *if* `option.innerText()` returns proper data (which I doubt), then get rid of all the await/async!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get the innerText? Then something like this would work:

```
// @ts-check
const playwright = require('playwright');

(async () => {
  const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch();
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();
  await page.goto('http://whatsmyuseragent.org/');
  await page.setContent(`
<div id="cdk-overlay-1" class="cdk-overlay-pane"> </div>
<div role="listbox" class="mat-autocomplete-panel" id="mat-autocomplete-1"> </div>
<mat-option role="option" class="mat-option mat-focus-indicator ng-star-inserted" id="mat-option-35">1</mat-option>
<mat-option role="option" class="mat-option mat-focus-indicator ng-star-inserted" id="mat-option-36">2</mat-option>
<mat-option role="option" class="mat-option mat-focus-indicator ng-star-inserted" id="mat-option-37">3</mat-option>
<mat-option role="option" class="mat-option mat-focus-indicator ng-star-inserted" id="mat-option-38">4</mat-option>
<mat-option role="option" class="mat-option mat-focus-indicator ng-star-inserted" id="mat-option-39">5</mat-option>
</div> `)
  const options = page.locator("mat-option[role='option']")
  const values = await options.allTextContents()
  console.log(values)
  await browser.close();
})()
```

See here for reference: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator

Comment: I would like to select one of the option in autocomplete dropdown. There is no Select tag and I can't select any option from the list. Yeah innerText return value.

Comment: Then see here: https://playwright.dev/docs/input#select-options